# UITableView scrolls up on reload

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, tableview

I am new to stackoverflow and relatively new to ***iOS*** development. I have a problem regarding the reload of `UITableView` which is driving me crazy. On selecting any row of a `UITableView` the table view moves up a little bit. I have reloaded the table view on `didSelect`, that is whenever  the user clicks on the `UITableViewCell`. I have used ***autolayout*** to calculate the height of the rows of the `UITableViewCell`. But whenever the table view row is clicked, the table view is scrolled a fair bit, i.e. the table view contents move up abruptly. Here is my code..

```
#pragma mark UITableView DELEGATES AND DATASOURCE

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;//enter code here
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.arr_display count];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //-----COMMENTED AUTOLAYOUT OUT TO TEST------HEIGHT IS KEPT STATICto 40-----

    [self configureCell:_stubCell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    [_stubCell layoutSubviews];

    // [_stubCell needsUpdateConstraints];
    // [_stubCell setNeedsLayout];

    CGFloat height = [_stubCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;
    return height + 1;

    //setNeedsUpdateConstraints

    // return 40;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 40.f;
}

- (void)configureCell:(cell_detail_search *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //cell.lbl.text = _tableData[indexPath.row % _tableData.count];
    // NSDictionary *dict=[[[[self.arr_display objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:1] valueForKey:@"info"] objectAtIndex:0];

    cell.lbl_skills.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.arr_display objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    if ([self.arr_selected_search_list containsObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.arr_display objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]])//-----GIVING TICK TO THE CELL
    {
        cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView1 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell_detail_search *cell = [tableView1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell==nil)
    {
        cell =[[cell_detail_search alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }

    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([self.arr_selected_search_list containsObject:[self.arr_display  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ])
    {
        // [self.arr_id_list removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.arr_selected_search_list removeObjectAtIndex:[self.arr_selected_search_list indexOfObject:[self.arr_display objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ]];

        self.str_comma_separated_selected_search_list=[self get_comma_separated_string_from_array:self.arr_selected_search_list];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.arr_selected_search_list addObject:[self.arr_display  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ];

        self.str_comma_separated_selected_search_list=[self get_comma_separated_string_from_array:self.arr_selected_search_list];

        NSLog(@"self.arr_id_list =%@",self.arr_selected_search_list);
    }

    [self.tbl_search_details reloadData];
}

#pragma mark scrollview delegate made for tableview pagination---------

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
    if ([str_heading isEqualToString:@"Skills"])
    {
        float diff=self.tbl_search_details.contentSize.height-self.tbl_search_details.frame.size.height;

    if (diff<0)
    {
        diff=0;
    }

    float drag_distance=self.tbl_search_details.contentOffset.y-diff;
    NSLog(@"drag distance %f",drag_distance);

    if (drag_distance>80)
    {
        [self.activity_pagination startAnimating];
        [self determining_the_api_to_call_with_str:self.str_heading];
    }     
}
```

I would be really grateful if anyone can help me out.....Thanks in advance

Comment: Looking at your code, I understand how you're struggling to locate the bug :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your cells are a fixed height then you don't need to implement `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath` or `heightForRowAtIndexPath` - you can just use a fixed height in your UITableView definition.

To update the "tick" accessory on selection you can just update the configuration directly, there is no need to reload the entire table view -

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    if([self.arr_selected_search_list containsObject:[self.arr_display  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ])
    {
        // [self.arr_id_list removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.arr_selected_search_list removeObjectAtIndex:[self.arr_selected_search_list indexOfObject:[self.arr_display objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ]];

        self.str_comma_separated_selected_search_list=[self get_comma_separated_string_from_array:self.arr_selected_search_list];

         }

    else
    {



        [self.arr_selected_search_list addObject:[self.arr_display  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ];

        self.str_comma_separated_selected_search_list=[self get_comma_separated_string_from_array:self.arr_selected_search_list];

        NSLog(@"self.arr_id_list =%@",self.arr_selected_search_list);
    }

    cell_detail_search *cell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];



}
```

Also, as a matter of style, class names should start with a capital letter, so your cell class should be `Cell_detail_search`, or even better `DetailSearchCell`

Finally, if you replace your arr_selected_search_list array with an `NSMutableIndexSet` you can simplify your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and `configureCell` methods

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if([self.selectedIndexSet containsIndex:indexPath.row])
    {
        [self.selectedIndexSet removeIndex:indexPath.row]; 
    }  
    else
    {
        [self.selectedIndexSet addIndex:indexPath.row]
    }

    cell_detail_search *cell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];   
}

- (void)configureCell:(cell_detail_search *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   cell.lbl_skills.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.arr_display objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

   if ([self.selectedIndexSet containsIndex:indexPath.row])
   {
    cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
   }
   else
   {
    cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
   }
}
```

Comment: good points though...but that does not solve my problem..as to why is the table scrolling up on did select....is it something related to autolayout....or what may be the reasons....

Comment: I don't know - I assumed it was something to do with the row heights and the reload of the entire table. Perhaps remove the scrollViewDidEndDragging stuff

Comment: I can achieve my result by your way without reloading the table. you saved my day.thanks!!...still wondering why would the table scroll up on reloading ..i have never seen this behaviour....have you got any idea...

Comment: another thing if i remove the autolayout part in tableview height delegate....then the tableview becomes normal.so it has to do something with autolayout..but cant really get a clear idea as to how autolayout may affect here..

Comment: I haven't ever had to use auto layout in table cells, but it is hard to say what the issue may be without seeing your constraints

Answer (score 0):

Add this before reloading your table.

[self.tbl_search_details setNeedsDisplay];

Answer (score 0):

One ofthe probable cause of the problem was the delegatee

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 40.0f;
}
```

My original row height was returning 80 but here it is given 40.. somehow the table jerked  because of this though it should not be..when i deliberately returned 80 in the estimated height section then the problem got solved...any body had this experience?.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar problem. However, I'm using constraints on the labels in my prototype cell and the following two lines in my viewDidLoad:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

This ensures that my cells are automatically sized to display all their content - which can vary from cell to cell (I followed the steps on this page http://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/ to achieve this).

To solve the problem of the scrolling tableView I first changed the estimatedRowHeight of the tableView to it's current value of 80 (it was at 66 before) and this stopped the table from scrolling up when I reloaded the selected cells. Additionally, after reloading the data in my tableView (I use the reloadRowsAtIndexPaths method) I call its scrollToRowAtIndexPath method. For example:

```
tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Middle, animated: true)
```

This scrolls the tableView to show all the content of the selected cell. I don't get the issue of the tableView scrolling up any more when I select a cell at the bottom of the tableView.

@user3744496 Did you ever manage to fix your problem?

Comment: If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button.

Comment: Okay, will do, I just wanted to see if user3744496 had manage to fix his problem :)